# Datatables - how to prevent word wrap in length menu and search dialog

Tags: javascript, html, datatables, bootstrap-5

I have implemented [Datatables](https://datatables.net) into my Spring MVC, Java, Bootstrap 5, Thymeleaf project and the results are great. The only issue is a cosmetic one - the text is wrapping in the length menu and search sections. This can be seen at the top of the attached image where "Show 10 entries" is split across 3 lines and the Search table and box are split over 2 lines.

[image: datatables-image]

I am using the latest versions of `jquery.dataTables.min.css`, `jquery.dataTables.min.js` and `dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js` with no custom configuration: -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('table.display').DataTable();
});
```

Here is an HTML snippet with one row of data:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>Java Documentum Services</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/dropzonejs/dropzone.css"/>
</head>
    <body>
        <div class="container pt-3 pb-3">
    <table id="search-results"
           class="display"
           style="width:100%">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Filename</th>
            <th>Test</th>
            <th>Case Id</th>
            <th>Upload Time</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                    <span>download.pdf</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span>JH-06062022-01</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span>test-case-12344444</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span>2022-07-22 11:03 GMT</span>
            </td>
            <td>
                <!--Actions button-->
                <!--Download button-->
                <!--Delete button-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
        <script src="/assets/jquery/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jquery/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jds/dataTables.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/dropzonejs/dropzone.min.js"></script>
        <script src="/assets/jds/dropzone.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I can see that these two sections are defined in `sLengthMenu` and `sSearch` in the JavaScript code, so perhaps a code change could be an option, but it would be preferable if it could be fixed with a configuration change instead. I also wondered if perhaps there is a clash with one of the other CSS stylesheets or JavaScript libraries that I am using - these are visible in the sample HTML.

Comment: You can compare your code with the [Bootstrap 5 example](https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap5.html) on the DataTables web site, where that wrapping issue does not happen. Perhaps caused by one or more of your CSS classes, as you noted - so start by removing those from the HTML as a test. (Also, the code in the question has an opening `<div>` but no closing `</div>`.)

Comment: @andrewJames Great, good spot regarding the <div> tag, and good suggestion regarding the CSS classes. I'll look into these - many thanks